# Join across multiple junction tables with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database with three primary tables: `users`, `teams`, and `folders` joined by two junction tables, `users_teams` and `teams_folders`. There is a many-to-many relationship between users and teams and between teams and folders (a user can be on more than one team and teams can own more than one folder).

Sequelize does a wonderful job of managing the user-teams and teams-folder relationship, but I can find no way to establish a relationship between users and folders.

**Is there any way to join across two junction tables without resorting to raw SQL?**

There seems to be no way to accomplish this elegantly or in a reasonable number of steps. I have tried methods like `user.getFolders()`, `Folder.findAll({ include: [User] })`, but Sequelize doesn't seem to be able to understand a three level hierarchy.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Assuming the following relations:

```
User.belongsToMany(Team, { through: 'users_teams'});
Team.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'users_teams'});

Folder.belongsToMany(Team, { through: 'teams_folders'});
Team.belongsToMany(Folder, { through: 'teams_folders'});
```

You should be able to load everything in one go using nested includes:

```
User.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Team, 
      include: [
        Folder
      ]  
    }
  ]
});
```

You seem to be on the right track already with the example you have given in your post :). The only thing you need to change is instead of passing the User model directly in `include`, you pass an object with a model property and a further nested include property

Comment: Embarrassingly, the real issue is that I didn't realize this method was referred to as "eager loading" and had skimmed over that section of the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that `hasMany` is supposed to be used with 1:M relations: `N:M associations are not supported with hasMany. Use belongsToMany instead`

Comment: With regards to the above is it possible to retrieve a folder that belongs to a user? Or you can only retrieve all of the folders that belong to a team for a user but no way of having different access to folders per user?

Answer (score 8):

Pay attention to following:

- Define relations in *both directions*
- Check you have foreignKey, otherKey in *correct order*

```
User.belongsToMany(Team, {
  through: 'users_teams',
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  otherKey: 'team_id'
});

Team.belongsToMany(User, {
  through: 'users_teams',
  foreignKey: 'team_id',
  otherKey: 'user_id'
});
```