# Sequelize help in associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

All, Attached below is a SQL query that I used as a raw query in sequelize and it worked fine. Now I am trying to setup it up with mixin associations in sequelize but unable to do so. Did go thru the help documentations but could not completely grasp the details. Maybe its just me. Anyway, attached below is the query that I am trying to rework. Would appreciate if anybody can throw some pointers or have some samples to help me rework this? Thanks in advance.

```
select cust.*, cust_role.id, cust_role.rolename, role.roletype
from
customer cust, customer_roles cust_role, roles role
where
cust.id = cust_role.user and
cust_role.role = role.id and
cust.id like '0123456' //customerId
```

table relationships

```
customer_roles has a foreign key to both roles and customer tables
customer to customer_roles (1 to many), 
customer_roles to roles (many to 1)
```

I am importing the models

```
var custModel = sequelize.import('../models/customer.js');
var custRolesModel = sequelize.import('../models/customer_roles.js');
var roleModel = sequelize.import('../models/roles.js');
```

trying to set the relationships

```
custModel.hasMany(custRolesModel);
custRolesModel.belongsTo(custModel);

roleModel.hasMany(custRolesModel);
custRolesModel.belongsTo(roleModel);
```

and finally trying to get the customer..

```
custModel.findAll({
  include:[{
    model:custRolesModel,
    include:[{
      model:roleModel,
      where: {
        username:req.body.username
      },
      required:false
    }]
  }]
}).then(function (result) {
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
custModel.findAll({
  where : {
    id:req.body.userId
  },
  include:[{
    model:custRolesModel,
    include:[{
      model:roleModel
    }]
  }]
}).then(function (result) {
......
```

Note that the where clause belongs to the customer model instead of the role model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried your suggestion and the generated SQL has incorrect associations. For example **`cust.id = cust_role.UserId`** , where **UserId** column is not present in **cust_role** table. There are few wrong associations like this. Any idea on why this might be happening and what I should look for?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the database after the model change? Columns are not altered by Sequelize. If you drop the database and use Sequelize.sync(), the column UserId should be present, assuming your associations are correctly set. From which model does UserId come from by the way?

Comment: Will try deleting the db. userid is in custModel.

Comment: Finally, I got this to work. A combination of your suggestion and another one in SO, was able to resolve this. I did not delete the database. Had kept it as a last resort. But anyway, thank you so much for you help. I have added my solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion from above and another suggestion one in SO, I was able to resolve it. This is what I did incase anybody needs to know.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36006808/1657861

Modified relationships

```
custModel.belongsToMany(custRolesModel, {
  through:'customer_roles', //Used table name
  foreignKey: 'user',
  otherKey:'id'
});

custRolesModel.belongsToMany(roleModel, {
  through: 'customer_roles', //Used table name
  foreignKey: 'role',
  otherKey: 'id'
});

usersModel.findAll({
  where : {
    username:req.body.username
  },
  include:[{
    model:userRolesMembershipModel,
    include:[{
      model:roleModel
    }]
  }]
})
```